# Using sed, how do I replace specific content in file?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have the following text in an xml file:

```
 <Connector port="8983" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the
         connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
         described in the APR documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->
```

as part of my build script, I need to replace the 8983 port with another port no, say 8181. So I need to change only the first line above (disregarding any line numbers, as this line could occur anywhere in the file). Also, the port number isn't to be relied on ,it's 8983 in this instance but it could be something else. To summarise: I need to change the digits in the first occurrence of the pattern `\Connector port="\d{4}" protocol="HTTP\/1.1$\`

I've tried

```
sed 's#Connector port="\d{4}" protocol="HTTP/1.1"#Connector port="8181" protocol="HTTP/1.1"#' -i server.xml
```

which doesn't error, but it has no effect on the file.

What's the best way to do this ?

PS: the server runs Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Why the backslash before Connector?

Comment: Need to escape `{}`, Also no need to escape connector or the following `#` separator.

Comment: you're both right, I had mixed up the delimiters. Now edited it to the correct command, however, it still doesn't work, i.e. it has no effect on the file.

Comment: you need to be certain (assuming) that your xml keep the same format that is only 1 way, if modification occur like several info on same line, the script if comming from text manipulation (awk, sed, ...) could faild. Use instead a xml parser for such a task when possible

Comment: @NeronLeVelu agree, but as this is part of a shell installation script I have to stick to cli utilities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux (I tested it on Ubuntu):

```
sed -i 's/Connector port="8983" protocol="HTTP\/1.1"/Connector port="8181" protocol="HTTP\/1.1"/' server.xml
```

On OSX (tested on 10.10):

```
sed -i '' 's/Connector port="8983" protocol="HTTP\/1.1"/Connector port="8181" protocol="HTTP\/1.1"/' server.xml
```

Comment: On OS X don't you need an argument after `-i`, e.g. `-i ""` to indicate that no backup file should be made?

Comment: This isn't working. The server.xml file is actually modified but the port value isn't changed. Weird.

Comment: @Barmar Indeed, an extra empty argument is needed. I thought that providing `-e` after `-i` will make it understand there is no need to backup but I was wrong. I modified the answer.

Comment: the extra argument is throwing this error:  sed: can't read s/Connector port="8983" protocol="HTTP\/1.1"/Connector port="8181" protocol="HTTP\/1.1"/: No such file or directory

Comment: OSX has a different syntax for `-i`. I updated the answer.